# facebook 'req_perms' and 'ext_perms ' what's the difference?

Tags: php, facebook, api, sdk

I'm using the facebook php sdk 2.1.2 in my web app.
I use the getLoginUrl method to request permission to the user who's logging in my site.

```
$facebook->getLoginUrl(array( 
'req_perms'=> 'email,read_stream,user_birthday,user_hometown,user_photos'));
```

I was wondering if there's a way User can ask for optional permission.And what's the difference between req_perms and ext_perms?

best regards

Answer (score 0):

req_perms are permissions that you can set as being 'required' by your application before they can begin using an application.

ext_perms are optional permissions that you can request to enhance the experience for users, the user has the option to specifically allow/disallow each of these permissions on an individual basis.

**edit: req_perms and ext_perms have been depreciated and are replaced by a the single 'scope' parameter (which the values will determine what permissions are optional) - *thanks Igy***

> ie: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/#extended_perms
>
> *If you are using the Enhanced Auth Dialog, extended permissions are presented on the second page of the dialog and are individually user-revocable. If you request these permissions, the user can choose to not grant one or more of them. Your application should not expect the user to always grant these permissions if requested.*

Comment: Both of those parameters in the original question are long-deprecated; currently `scope` is the parameter used